# React Native Section Headers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to use section headers in my listview. My data comes like following:

```
[
  {name: 'ShouldBeSection1', locations: [{id: 2121, name: "School"}, {id: 4545, name: "Los Angeles"}]},
  {name: 'ShouldBeSection2', locations: [{id: 4545, name: "Work"}, {id: 4545, name: "New York"}, {id: 4545, name: "Sports"}]},
  {name: 'ShouldBeSection3', locations: [{id: 8786, name: "University"}]},
]
```

the name should be obviously my section header and locations is the row data below the sections. Any hints ? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to transform your incoming data to match format required by react native

From docs, list view data will be of form

```
 { sectionID_1: [ <rowData1>, <rowData2>, ... ], ... }
```

So you should write a method which does the transformation for you.

```
getListData(data) {
  var rowAndSectionData = {

  };
  data.forEach(function(rowData){

     rowAndSectionData[rowData.name] = rowData.locations;

  });

  return rowAndSectionData;

}
```

Now use the returned value as source instead of original data.

Comment: great, upvote .. I need a consultation: as a top user in *react native* tag, do you think is learning it worthy?! Someone says it's perfect, someone else says that's a terrible idea .. So I'm confused, I want to make a mobile application (both for Android and iOS operation systems), well, is it possible to make professional apps by *react native*? Or react native just lets us to make beginner apps? Also what about the quality of apps which have been created by *react native*? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I try it and it works. I hope it's fine for you.

```
                import React from 'react';
                import {Table, Column, Cell} from 'fixed-data-table';

                class MyTable extends React.Component {

                  constructor(props) {
                    super(props);
                    this.state = {
                      rows : [
          {name: 'ShouldBeSection1', locations: [{id: 2121, name: "School"}, {id: 4545, name: "Los Angeles"}]},
          {name: 'ShouldBeSection2', locations: [{id: 4545, name: "Work"}, {id: 4545, name: "New York"}, {id: 4545, name: "Sports"}]},
          {name: 'ShouldBeSection3', locations: [{id: 8786, name: "University"}]}]  };
          }

                  render() {
                      return <Table
                        height={40+((this.state.rows.length+1) * 30)}
                        width={1150}
                        rowsCount={this.state.rows.length}
                        rowHeight={30}
                        headerHeight={30}
                        rowGetter={function(rowIndex) {return this.state.rows[rowIndex]; }.bind(this)}>
                        <Column dataKey="name" width={50} label="Name" />
                        <Column dataKey="locations[0].name" width={200} label="First Location" />
                        <Column dataKey="locations[1].name" width={200} label="Second Location" />
                        <Column dataKey="locations[2].name" width={200} label="Second Location" />

                      </Table>;
                  }
                }

                module.exports = MyTable;
```

Comment: Okay thanks for your reply. But import {Table, Column, Cell} from 'fixed-data-table'; is not a react-native component?! I need to have this dynamical and for a ListView from react-native.

Comment: I found 2 valuable link. I hope these are fine for you; http://moduscreate.com/react-native-dynamic-animated-lists/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39359171/listview-with-a-dynamic-object-issue